# How to add a black rectangle in left side of every page in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I really need to add a simple black box (rectangle) on left side of my pages in LaTeX with a fixed position. I have added a sample image.
There isn't any concern with using an SVG file or just draw this box.

P.S.: Does this black rectangle have a name in English?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 8):

No need to use TikZ in your case, a simple `\rule` with `eso-pic` package is enough.

I think the English words for these things are "border" or "frame".

Of course, this works also with multiple pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\rule{1cm}{\paperheight}%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext% <--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the black line on the left for odd pages and on the right for even pages, just test `\thepage` with `\ifnumodd` of `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only

\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\mylen}{-1cm}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\ifnumodd{\thepage}{\rule{\mylen}{0cm}\rule{1cm}{\paperheight}}{\rule{1cm}{\paperheight}}%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]% <--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is one solution with rectangle on the left of each page:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm, top=3.75cm, bottom=3.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    color=black,
    contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=black] ([xshift=1cm,yshift=0cm] current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=.0cm,yshift=0cm] current page.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-27]
\end{document}
```

[image: Solution with rectangle on the left]

If you want the rectangle on the left side for even page and on the right side for odd pages here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm, top=3.75cm, bottom=3.5cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[all]{background}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    color=black,
    contents={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
            \checkoddpage % to comment if you want only left side
            \ifoddpage % to comment if you want only left side
            \draw[fill=black] ([xshift=-.5cm,yshift=0cm] current page.south east) rectangle ([xshift=-0cm,yshift=0cm] current page.north east); % to comment if you want only left side
            \else % to comment if you want only left side
            \draw[fill=black] ([xshift=.5cm,yshift=0cm] current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] current page.south west);
            \fi % to comment if you want only left side 
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-27]
\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image: Solution with rectangle on the left and right]

Answer (score 2):

Using `framed.sty`

```
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}
...
\end{leftbar}
```